# Robotium how to click on UILabel in LinearLayout

Tags: android, robotium

i'm new to android automation ,here is my problem :  i am testing Apk file,i don't have resource code.i want to click  UILabel in the LinearLayout ,AS is shown in the following chart。
Please help me out. Thanks.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6vdH.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(TextLayout.class, 1));
```

or

```
solo.clickOnView(((LinearLayout)solo.getView("toolLayout")).getChildAt(1));
```

I'm not sure about index (1 or 2)

Comment: solo.clickOnView(((LinearLayout)solo.getView("toolLayout")).getChildAt(1));  YES，IT Works,TKS.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the url below for testing apk files

https://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/RobotiumForAPKFiles

well as you said you haven't got source code which means you don't know which Id the UI element is! so you can directly access ui labels from text and if you are unsure that ui element is visible then you can use **solo.waitForText** to wait till it is visible.

solo.clickOnText("your text to be clicked");

Comment: TKS.i have tried slo.clickOnText() ,it's not working ,it's not a text.

Comment: Try click on button or what ever ui element just go through the available methods in solo